# Fastq to fasta format with sed/awk command

Tags: bash, awk, sed, fastq

I have a data with fastq format:

```
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1522:2491 2:N:0:CGTACG
GTGCCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTGCGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNGCAGATACTCGTANNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+
@BCFF###########################################################################
#####################
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1668:2494 2:N:0:CGTACG
TCTTTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTNTGTTTTACGGTTTNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+
C@CFF###########################################################################
#####################
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:2557:2492 2:N:0:CGTACG
CCTCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNCAACACACTCCTCNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+
CCCFF###########################################################################
#####################
```

and I want to split each read with "+" used awk command, but it didnt't work,
Is there simple command with see/awk can convert it into fasta format?

The expect output should be

```
>HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1522:2491 2:N:0:
CGTACGGTGCCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTGCGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNGCAGATACTCGTANNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1668:2494 2:N:0:
CGTACGTCTTTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTNTGTTTTACGGTTTNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:2557:2492 2:N:0:
CGTACGCCTCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNCAACACACTCCTCNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition, I hope the last six reads of first line can merge with other reads, thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use awk? If not, try googling: fastq to fasta.

Comment: if you expect your readers to know what `fast(a) format` "looks like", you're greatly reducing the number of people that can help you. Consider editing your question to include the required output given your sample data. Also recall that `RS="+";ORS="\n"` will tell `awk` to split records at each '+' char, and write out revised records with just a newline char. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following

```
awk -f conv.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input data file, and `conv.awk` is

```
/@HISEQ/ { p=1; sub(/^@/,">"); sub(/:[^:]*$/,":"); print; next }
/^\+/ {p=0}
p==1 { print }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '((/@/&&$0!~/#/)||$0!~/#/)&&$0!~/\+/' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp2
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1522:2491 2:N:0:CGTACG
GTGCCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTGCGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNGCAGATACTCGTANNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+
@BCFF###########################################################################
#####################
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1668:2494 2:N:0:CGTACG
TCTTTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTNTGTTTTACGGTTTNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+
C@CFF###########################################################################
#####################
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:2557:2492 2:N:0:CGTACG
CCTCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNCAACACACTCCTCNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+
CCCFF###########################################################################
#####################
>
> nawk '((/@/&&$0!~/#/)||$0!~/#/)&&$0!~/\+/' temp2
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1522:2491 2:N:0:CGTACG
GTGCCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTGCGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNGCAGATACTCGTANNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:1668:2494 2:N:0:CGTACG
TCTTTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTNTGTTTTACGGTTTNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
@HISEQ:157:C11RCACXX:6:1101:2557:2492 2:N:0:CGTACG
CCTCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNCAACACACTCCTCNNNNNNNNGCNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a nice code, but I expect the last 6 reads of first line should be merge with other reads.